# passing binary data another thread

Tags: c++

I have a API that takes binary data and internally it has to push that in to a queue and another thread reads from the queue and process the data.

I would like to avoid allocating dynamic memory allocation.

My API is like

```
bool some_func(unsigned char* data, int length);
```

Should I use `stringstream` as argument to handle binary data?

Thank you

Comment: Read some [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) then adapt that knowledge to your C++11 threads, if you use these

Comment: Maybe a `std::vector<uint8_t>` seems to be more suitable.

Comment: You will have to use the dynamic memory allocation in any case (but not each time you are put data into queue, i.e. new will be called only once). Check [this](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.lockfree)

Comment: My concern was on the life time of the data passed. Since the other thread may not know whether the address is still referring to a valid data.Can I use a shared_ptr as API argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to avoid allocating dynamic memory allocation
>
> Should I use stringstream as argument to handle binary data?

I think you will be disappointed with most of the std  containers, and with stringstream in particular.

---

For example, on Lubuntu 18.04 (64 bit), std::stringstream uses a std::string as its buffer.

sizeof(std::string ) with **no** data reports 32 bytes.

sizeof(std::string) with **1,000,000** chars in it, reports 32 bytes, while s.size() reports 1,000,000.

( These are implementation details which I have investigated on 18.04. )

More clearly: the 1M chars in the std::string (in the stringstream) are allocated to dynamic memory. The container objects are simply performing the dynamic memory allocation and handling for you.

---

The std::vector also uses dynamic memory.  sizeof (std::vector) reports 24 bytes.  For "std::vector v;" with 1000 elements, sizeof(v) is 24, and v.size() is 1000.  The container is performing the dynamic memory handling.

---

You can not use vector or string to avoid dynamic memory allocation.

Now ask yourself why you wish to avoid it, and are you sure you need to?

Consider that you can allocate your buffers once at the beginning of your effort.

Comment: If, by  "I want to avoid dynamic memory allocation"  you mean you wish to avoid  writing the new's and deletes of buffers ... then yes ... stringstream or simply string will take care of the error prone activity on your behalf, and would simplify your effort.

Comment: std::ostringstream inherits from basic_ostream, and thus has a binary write method.  etc.  You can do binary in/out to the stringstream's.